# href link not working on overlapping divs

Tags: html, css

I have two divs that overlap horizontally. My issue is that one of the divs contain text and a href link which is not working.

You can see the code I have here
https://jsfiddle.net/jayreis/w7regdcr/

```
 .postwrapper
 {   
    margin:auto;
    width:80%;
    display:block;
    padding-bottom:15px;
 }
 .imageDiv
 {
        margin-left: 100px;
        background: #fff;
        display: block;
        width: 445px;
        height: 220px;
        padding: 10px;
      border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
 }
.imageDiv img
{
  width:600px;
  height:400px;
}
.textboxDiv
{
  position:relative;
  bottom:145px;
  left:470px;
  zoom: 1; /*to fix the has layout bug in IE older version*/
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  opacity: 0.9;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  text-align:center;
}
.textboxDiv:after
{
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: -15px;
  right: -15px;
  bottom: -15px;
  border: #dddddd 2px solid

}
.readarticle
{
  text-decoration:none;
  border-top: 1px solid #a61531;
  float:left;
  color:#000000;
  z-index: 99999;
}


   <div class="postwrapper">
        <div class="imageDiv">
               <img src="http://www.ccc.com/media/post/image/6/0/600x400.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="imageDiv textboxDiv">
           <p style="color:#000000; margin-auto; width:35%; margin-left:-10px; padding-bottom:10px">date here
            </p>
           <h4><a href='http://www.ccc.com' title="" style="color:#000000; font-size:15px">the title</a></h4>
           <p style="color:#000000">desc here</p>
           <br />
            <p><a href="http://www.ccc.com" title="test" class='readarticle'>READ ARTICLE</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So if you look at the css if I change the  position: absolute; to be  position: relative; in the class style .textboxDiv:after the link then works but I loose the border style I need around the box.

Any suggestions how I can keep the style yet make the links work in the textboxDiv ??

Answer (score 1):

`.readarticle` is not positioned, so the z-index won't work. Simply add `position: relative;` and it'll work.

```
  .readarticle
  {
    text-decoration:none;
    border-top: 1px solid #a61531;
    float:left;
    color:#000000;
    z-index: 99999;
+   position: relative;
  }
```

[MDN Documentation: Z-Index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)